# Postgres perform calculation on column but keep results within range

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have the following table

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 8 | -2 |
| 10 | 0 |

And I want to add a third column in sql that represents the difference between each row, which I would do like so

```
select *, foo - bar as fuz
from mytable
```

Pretty simple. But let's say I wanted to keep the result of that fuz column to a min or max depending on whether the result was higher than my max or lower than my min.

So if the result of my query was this:

| foo | bar | fuz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | -1 |
| 3 | 10 | -7 |
| 2 | 5 | -3 |
| 8 | -2 | 10 |
| 10 | 0 | 10 |

But I wanted to make my minimum and maximum `fuz` values 5 and -5, then my result would look like this:

| foo | bar | fuz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | -1 |
| 3 | 10 | -5 |
| 2 | 5 | -2 |
| 8 | -2 | 5 |
| 10 | 0 | 5 |

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: How is "2 - 5 = -2"?  Presumably that is a typo.

Comment: yes, you're right, typo, i'll fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional logic:

```
select foo, bar,
       (case when foo - bar < -5 then -5
             when foo - bar > 5 then 5
             else foo - bar
        end)
from t;
```

Alternatively:

```
select foo, bar,
       least(greatest(foo - bar, -5), 5)
from t;
```

This one is a little harder to understand but more concise.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8276bf59d7b225040e8e7904a3f07787) is a db<>fiddle.